# Find the letter with most occurrences in a string, and print just the letter, not the count

Tags: python

How can I find the letter with most appearances from a string, and only output the letter, not the count?
With collections.Counter, it always displays the count as well as the letter. Current output: ('l', 3) . Preferred output: l

```
import collections
s = "helloworld"
print(collections.Counter(s).most_common(1)[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
print(collections.Counter(s).most_common(1)[0])
```

You can write

```
print(collections.Counter(s).most_common(1)[0][0])
```

It will give you the first element of the tuple, so the output will be `l`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like:

```
txt = "aaaaaaaabbbbbcccdde"
print(max(set(txt), key=txt.count))
```

output:

```
a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `max()` function with another function as the `key` parameter like this:

```py
s = "helloworld"
print(max(s, key = lambda c: s.count(c)))
```

The `key` parameter is a function to be used when comparing two items of the `s` iterable. In this case, we compare based on the occurrence of each item.